# Пишу небольшую программу на python для погоды

Tags: python

Часть кода вот.

```
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM('2b81034cf1e96c904e721b0da1ad3f9d', language="ru")
place = input("В каком городе/стране вы бы хотели узнать погоду?: ")
observation = own.weather_at_place(place)
w=observation.get_weather()
print(w)
```

Выдаёт ошибку на строке "observation..."
Не могу понять, почему?
Написано всё верно, вроде.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, проблему.

Comment: Какую именно ошибку?

Comment: Чтобы понять почему, нужно прочитать текст ошибки.

Comment: замени на mgr
замени на mgr
замени на mgr
замени на mgr

Answer (score 6):

Ваш код выдаёт следующее исключение:

```py
NameError: name 'own' is not defined
```

В переводе оно означает:

> Ошибка имени: имя `own` не определено

---

И ведь действительно, если вы внимательно присмотритесь, переменной `own` нет в Вашем коде. Перед тем, как её использовать, её нужно определить.

Скорее всего, Вы опечатались и имели в виду `owm`, то есть:

```py
observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
```